# Taking Class, Course, Lecture - Which verb is fit?

Tags: verbs, words, idioms, word-choice

I would like to know how we say taking class or course or lecture in japanese.

I have heard about　「クラスを受ける」　and 「クラスを取る」.

Are there significant difference? And Is there any other verb we can use with?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Within relevant contexts, `受ける` means 'to attend' whereas `取る` means 'to be registered for'. If you are unofficially attending a class, you should use the former. If you are officially registered but tend to be absent, you should use the latter. Formal ways of saying it are `受講する` 'to be registered for', `聴講する` 'to be registered as a non-full time student for'.

Comment: What do you mean "tend to be absent" in「取る」's meaning？ If I won't be absent any period of the class, then I can't use 「取る」?

Comment: If you are registered and are not absent, then you can use either depending on which aspect you are focusing on.